# Flask SecureCookie replacing pickle with json results in encoding error

Tags: python, session, flask, werkzeug

Below is werkzeug's recommendation for session serialization:

> The default implementation uses Pickle as this is the only module that
>   used to be available in the standard library when this module was
>   created. If you have simplejson available it’s strongly recommended to
>   create a subclass and replace the serialization method:

When I do this following both the Flask implementation below:

https://gist.github.com/runfalk/2501926

or alternatively

```
from werkzeug.contrib.securecookie import SecureCookie
Secure_Cookie.serialization_method = json
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 0:
>   invalid start byte

This happens when I attempt to login.

I have delved into the json encoder source and attempted to set `ensure_ascii=False` and this got me past the error above but then I just couldn't log into the application at all. It would just flash the screen with no error and I remained stuck at the login prompt. With pickle everything works fine.

An important side note this problem is unique to the integration of the `Flask-login`  and does not occur with just the vanilla `flask` session serialization

ASKSBADQUESTIONS's code does indeed work but this throws the decode error

```
import json

from flask import Flask, session
from flask.sessions import SecureCookieSession, SecureCookieSessionInterface
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager

class JSONSecureCookieSession(SecureCookieSession):
    serialization_method = json

class JSONSecureCookieSessionInterface(SecureCookieSessionInterface):
    session_class = JSONSecureCookieSession

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "I-like-cookies-and-some-secure-cookies"
app.session_interface = JSONSecureCookieSessionInterface()

#Initialize Login Manager
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.setup_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    k = "lalala"

    v = session.get(k)

    if v is None:
        print "set"
        v = session[k] = "FLAAASK abuses decorators in a bad way :)"
    else:
        print "get"

    return "Hello {0}".format(v)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here is the stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1362, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1566, in process_response
    self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 804, in save_session
    return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 205, in save_session
    secure=secure, domain=domain)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/securecookie.py", line 329, in save_cookie
    data = self.serialize(session_expires or expires)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/securecookie.py", line 235, in serialize
    self.quote(value)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.3/flask-session-bug/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/contrib/securecookie.py", line 192, in quote
    value = cls.serialization_method.dumps(value)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.3/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 195, in encode
    return encode_basestring_ascii(o)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 0: invalid start byte
set
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a method in `flask_login.py` called `_create_identifier`. The result of this invocation is a md5 `digest()` result. According to the docs this can contain non-ascii characters and/or null bytes. When handed to the `serialization_method` it is unable to decode the unicode bytes.

This bug definitely exists in the combination of Flask 0.9 and Flask-login 0.1.3 and can be fixed by monkey patching this gist(https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3731115) into the flask_login.py file or you can pull the latest out of development.

You can refer to this bug on their github repo if you need more info
https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/pull/31

Answer (score 1):

I quickly wrote minimal Flask app to reproduce your bug (saved into `app.py`; invoked with `python app.py`):

```
import json

from flask import Flask, session
from flask.sessions import SecureCookieSession, SecureCookieSessionInterface


class JSONSecureCookieSession(SecureCookieSession):
    serialization_method = json


class JSONSecureCookieSessionInterface(SecureCookieSessionInterface):
    session_class = JSONSecureCookieSession


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "I-like-cookies-and-some-secure-cookies"
app.session_interface = JSONSecureCookieSessionInterface()


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    k = "lalala"

    v = session.get(k)

    if v is None:
        print "set"
        v = session[k] = "FLAAASK abuses decorators in a bad way :)"
    else:
        print "get"

    return "Hello {0}".format(v)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But everything went smoothly. I even changed [`session_interface`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.session_interface) from Pickle-based to JSON-based few times, and did not get exception. Perhaps you should post full exception traceback and (maybe) add some code to my example to reproduce a bug.

Comment: So I continued experimenting. I dropped your code in there and it works fine. I then integrated your code into mine step-by-step. What I found is the minute I initialize the login manager from the Flask-Login extension is when I start getting the error.

Comment: So if you check my example above you see that it appears to be unique to integrating the Flask-login module